# What is the relationship between anger management difficulties and ADHD?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, adhd, psychology

According to Wikipedia, "Difficulties managing anger are more common in children with ADHD"

Is it that the anger is due to ADHD specifically? Is the anger suggestive of a comorbid disorder? Could it be either?

Answer (score 3):

Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder (ADHD) is a type of Neuro-developmental condition whose signs can be seen during early childhood.

ADHD is related to **hyperactive behavior, attention difficulties or difficulty in controlling behavior.** ADHD can affect an individual’s ability, whether at school or work depending on the symptoms.

Usually, the majority of individuals with ADHD tend to have problems with aggression and emotional control.

Anger outbursts individuals with ADHD are often **excessive and explosive**. Some individuals may hyperfocus on their anger and frightened when they lose control and have difficulty understanding their outbursts.

ADHD is strongly associated with **Oppositional Defiant Disorder (ODD)** and can interfere with the successful treatment of ADHD.

I am a teacher at **Accel Centre**, and there are a few students suffering from *hyperactive behavior* while in the class.

This happens because many children and teenagers are unaware of being overly angry or otherwise they are unable to identify the origin of their anger.

On the flip side, many people with ADHD seem to only be able to focus their attention on something they enjoy doing.

References:

*http://www.childhealing.com/articles/adhd.php*

*https://www.myvmc.com/diseases/attention-deficit-hyperactivity-disorder-in-adults-adult-adhd/*

Comment: wait actually is this relevant? [ADHD and Emotional Dysregulation: What You Need to Know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kew2JhKq3Y) i think there's no point asking this question if emotional stuff wasn't removed from DSM or something

Comment: thanks Dorian Townsend!